# Why cursor on button switches once title comes up?

Tags: html, css

I noticed that if button has title, once it appears, cursor changes from `pointer` to `default`. Why is that happening and how can it be prevented?

```css
button{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button title='Title'>Hover over me!</button>
```

As many commented that they can't see it, I made a screenshot:
[image]

My setup:

- MacBook Pro
- macOS Ventura 13.3.1(a)
- Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: When i run the code snippet I see a pointer on hover.

Comment: @Stu — it's a pointer on hover at first, but once the title pops up, the cursor becomes an arrow, at least in Chrome. Maybe it's a matter of setting what kind of pointer the title attribute receives.

Comment: @ralph.m I just tried it in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. The cursor remains a pointer at all times while hovering over the button. This must be a weird bug....

Comment: Nope sorry the cursor remains a pointer at least in a few different versions of Chrome I have (108.0.5359.125) and (115.0.5790.99)

Comment: I just tried it in a range of browsers on Mac. It actually worked on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I was wrong before: it only had the weird effect described by the OP in Brave.

Comment: @Alyona — It might be worth posting a picture and saying what browser you're seeing this in, as the comments above show that most people don't see this and don't quite believe you! I only see what you're describing in Brave (of the browsers I've tried).

Comment: You can always add your own style to buttons and not rely on browser specific styles.

Comment: I am also having this issue on my MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura with an up to date version of Chrome.